# How to list ODBC Drivers Installed in Vb.Net?

Tags: vb.net, list, odbc, drivers

How to list Drivers ODBC in Vb.Net? (Visual Studio 2015)

```
    Dim _Software As RegistryKey
    Dim _ODBC As RegistryKey
    _Software = Registry.LocalMachine
    _ODBC = _Software.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI")
    For Each XDrives In _ODBC.GetValueNames()
        MsgBox(XDrives)
    Next
```

Comment: Use "SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers".